# why is nullpointerexception thrown in this code in Java?

Tags: java, class, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am unable to trace through why null pointer exception is thrown here, I am sure it is pretty simple, but somehow I am missing it. It is thrown when the `checkoutBook` method is called. Any help here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


class Library {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
    Library() {

        HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    }


    public void checkoutBook(String isbn, String patron) {

        if (checkoutBooks.containsKey(isbn)) {
         checkoutBooks.get(isbn).add(patron);
        } else {
            List<String> patronlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            patronlist.add(patron);
            checkoutBooks.put(isbn, patronlist);
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Library library = new Library();
        library.checkoutBook("000", "Cay Horstman");
       library.checkoutBook("000", "Sharron Morrow");

     }

}
```

Comment: The stack trace tells you the line, and the line tells you what variable is null. You're really expected to be able to sort out NPEs by yourself. At least I expect it.

Comment: Once you have the code working, post it for review (to learn some simple best practices in Java) on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't assign any value to this variable:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
```

You just defined new one in constructor. So remove that instance `checkoutBooks` variable, or do this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


class Library {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
    Library() {

        checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    }


    public void checkoutBook(String isbn, String patron) {

        if (checkoutBooks.containsKey(isbn)) {
         checkoutBooks.get(isbn).add(patron);
        } else {
            List<String> patronlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            patronlist.add(patron);
            checkoutBooks.put(isbn, patronlist);
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Library library = new Library();
        library.checkoutBook("000", "Cay Horstman");
       library.checkoutBook("000", "Sharron Morrow");

     }

}
```

Comment: Naha...it happened to everyone. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't initialize the **field** `checkoutBooks` in the constructor.  You initialized a local variable with the same name.  Change your constructor to this:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
Sandbox() {

    checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Library constructor, you declare a local variable named `checkoutBooks`, and initialize it, but you don't initialize the same-named field at class level. Some suggestions:

1. At a minimum, to fix the error, change the constructor to do assignment only rather than declaring a new variable:

   ```
   Library() {
       checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
   }
   ```
2. Since you're not reassigning the `checkoutBooks` field after construction, you can declare the field `final`. Then it will catch this sort of error immediately at compile time, because `final` fields are required to be initialized. It also prevents accidental reassignment of the field later, which enhances robustness.

   ```
   class Library {
       final HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
       ...
   ```
3. Since you don't do anything else in the constructor, you can inline the initialization directly into the field declaration:

   ```
   class Library {
       final HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
       // no constructor
       ...
   ```
4. As of Java 7, you can avoid repeating the type arguments by using `<>`:

   ```
   class Library {
       final HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks = new HashMap<>();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`checkoutBooks.containsKey`
 is null when you used  `HashMap<String, List<String>>  checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();` inside constructor, thats why getting Exception

```
class Library {

    HashMap<String, List<String>> checkoutBooks;
    Library() {

       checkoutBooks = new HashMap<String, List<String>>(); // just change here 

    }


    public void checkoutBook(String isbn, String patron) {

        if (checkoutBooks.containsKey(isbn)) {
         checkoutBooks.get(isbn).add(patron);
        } else {
            List<String> patronlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            patronlist.add(patron);
            checkoutBooks.put(isbn, patronlist);
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        Library library = new Library();
        library.checkoutBook("000", "Cay Horstman");
       library.checkoutBook("000", "Sharron Morrow");

     }

}
```